# How to upload file using java script?

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I need to upload a file to the tomcat server from my html page, How can I do that?
Basically give me a clean & simple idea and some samples?
Searched a lot but can't understand this is totally new to me, am a bb app developer.

For desinging used a form in that used input type = file and a button

I don't get an idea how to start with the functionality. Anyone plz help me?

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is being voted down. It's a beginner question, but a common one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use js to upload anything. You send the file to a php script that saves it.

Check this.

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php